# hidraw* access through serial terminal (raspberry pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, pyserial, hid

So I've been trying to communicate with an inverter that uses the usb port to communicate. The device shows up as hidraw0 I've had no luck using the hidapi library, so far the only successful form of communication I've been able to establish is through GTKterm which somehow can open the hid device if I configure the port to read/write from '/dev/hidraw0'. So, I had the idea to make a simple serial terminal program using pyserial but when I try to connect it to the '/dev/hidraw0' it gives me invalid syntax.

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial
import binascii

def send_data():

    data = input_entry.get().strip()
    if data:

        hex_data = data.replace(" ", "").strip()
        byte_data = binascii.unhexlify(hex_data)
        serial_port.write(byte_data)
        display_sent_data(hex_data)

def display_sent_data(data):
    sent_data_text.insert(tk.END, data + "\n")


def read_data():

    data = serial_port.read_all()
    if data:

        hex_data = binascii.hexlify(data).decode()
        display_received_data(hex_data)

def display_received_data(data):

    received_data_text.insert(tk.END, data + "\n")

    # Scroll to the end of the received data text
    received_data_text.see(tk.END)



# Serial port configuration
serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', baudrate=38400, timeout=0.1)  # Replace with your actual serial port configuration



# GUI setup
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Serial Terminal")
window.geometry("400x300")



# Input entry and send button

input_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=30)
input_entry.pack(pady=10)

send_button = tk.Button(window, text="Send", command=send_data)
send_button.pack()



# Sent data display
sent_data_text = tk.Text(window, height=8, width=40)
sent_data_text.pack(pady=10)



# Received data display
received_data_text = tk.Text(window, height=8, width=40)
received_data_text.pack()



# Read data from serial port
def read_serial():

    read_data()
    window.after(100, read_serial)


read_serial()

window.mainloop()
```

I'm new here so apologies if my formatting is not correct, I've attached the code here it works with other serial devices. I've also tried changing permissions from Udev to make the device r/w and added it to plugdev but no luck. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't for the life of me get it to work in the way I wanted so I gave up and went back to using the hidapi, it works after giving permissions in udev and then running the script with Sudo, if anyone has a better solution than this I'd be glad to hear it. assigning permissions to my user doesn't work for some reason its only when running the hidapi script as Sudo

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).